# Why can't i declare a field using var

Tags: c#, var, static-typing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why class fields cannot be var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461597/why-class-fields-cannot-be-var)

I'd like to avoid typing out complex/long type definitions for fields like you can with local variables.

I'd like to know why this couldn't be done?

```
public class Foo
{
    public var barField = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // Does not work

    public void Method()
    {
        var barLocal = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // Works
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight from the source:

[Why no `var` on fields?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx)

Comment: +1 (and accept when i can), answers the 'why', which was my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have global vars.  Please check the remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

Comment: The question is asking *why* this can't be done - not just the fact that it can't.