# Declare var outside functions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

why i can't declare for example var myVar="myvariable" as a global variable in a class?. Is there any way to do it?.

Comment: Then what's the use of `class`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why class fields cannot be var?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461597/why-class-fields-cannot-be-var)

Answer (score 9):

> why i can't declare for example var myVar="myvariable" as a global variable in a class?.

Because that's how the [designers of the C# language](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx) decided to implement it.

> Is there any way to do it?.

No, there isn't.

Comment: could you elaborate why? why did the designers take that decision?

Comment: @naveen, did you read the blog post that I linked to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx It's written by one of the designers of the C# compiler and in it he explains the reason.

Comment: no i din't. i edited eric lippert as designers in my earlier post before submitting.

Answer (score 3):

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type var

Because of C# specification they're only at a method scope.

Answer (score 1):

No, var is only for locally scoped variables. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a keyword, usually used for the anonymous types.
Then declaring the field or global variable, you must explicitly set the real type for your field.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

> - `var` can only be used when a local variable is declared and
>     initialized in the same statement; the variable cannot be initialized
>     to null, or to a method group or an anonymous function.
> - `var` cannot be used on fields at class scope.
> - Variables declared by using var cannot be used in the
>     initialization expression. In other words, this expression is legal:
>     `int i = (i = 20)`; but this expression produces a compile-time error:
>     `var i = (i = 20)`;
> - Multiple implicitly-typed variables cannot be initialized in the
>     same statement.
> - If a type named var is in scope, then the var keyword will resolve
>     to that type name and will not be treated as part of an implicitly
>     typed local variable declaration.

See also:
[Eric Lippert opinion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Implicit type can only be placed in method scope as local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a static variable.

For example

```
    public class AGlobalVar 
{ 
    public static int AVar = 10; 

}
```

You should be able to access the variable anywhere in the application. To access it just go AGlobalVar.AVariable.